# Mongo DB get all fields using $project stage

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, aggregation

I have an aggregation pipeline, and `fields` variable.
`fields` contains an array of field names I want to return from the query, and it's **optional**.

for example, if I have the collection `users`, and inside it I have a doc looks like:

```json
{
  _id: "q98347r8943"
  firstName: "Bob",
  lastName: "Kugel",
  age: "18" 
}
```

and `fields` contains: `[{firstName: 1}]`

I want to use- `$project` stage like this:

```
$project {
  ...fields
}
```

It works fine, but in case `"fields"` is falsy (`[]`, `null`, `undefined`) I want the `$project` to return all doc's fields

How can I do it?

Comment: For my opinion, you can check whether `fields` is falsy, if it is falsy, then you don't need to add the $project stage, by default it will return all fields, $project stage is used to control how is the output.

Comment: btw empty array is not falsy. also when you spread an array doesnt it become like `$project { 0 : {firstName: 1},... }`